# How do I reinstall the DataNucleus plugin in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I installed the DataNucleus plugin in my installation of Eclipse.  How do I remove and reinstall the plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside Eclipse

go to Winows->preference on left side panel check for Install/Update->Available Software 
click on the plugin and right side click on remove this will remove the plugin .

In order to reinstall  click on Add button and the url of the plugin site and click , if it is compatible with the version of eclipse working , else it will display error

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Inside Eclipse (Helios)

Go to Help > Install New Software
Click on 'What is already installed?" link.
Select plugin and click Uninstall...

The suggested alternative of Windows > Preferences > Install/Update > Avail Software Sites > Remove doesn't remove the plugin - only the site.